# Error: Called end on pool more than once at BoundPool.end

Tags: node.js, pg-promise, node-postgres

When I try to fetch data from PostgreSQL using pg-promise, it throws an error

> Error: Called end on pool more than once
> at BoundPool.end (/workspace/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:381:19)
> at Database.pool.end.cb (/workspace/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/database.js:133:31)

```js
app.get("/route/:id", async (req: any, res: any) => {
    const key = req.params.id;
    let status: number;
    let response: any = {};
    console.log(key);
    await db.any('SELECT * FROM "schema"."my_table" WHERE key = $1', [key])
        .then(data => {
            status = 200;
            response = {
                'status': 'success',
                'data': JSON.stringify(data)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            status = 406;
            response = {
                'status': 'failed',
                'error': error.message,
                'errorCode': error.code
            }
        })
        .finally(db.$pool.end);
    res.status(status).send(response);
});
```

When should I end the connection pool?
Will it end automatically when the response is success?

Comment: Where did you find an example of calling `.finally(db.$pool.end);` at the end of an API call? You are destroying the connection pool after every API call, hence the error.

Comment: Shouldn't I end it manually? will it be handled automatically?

Comment: yes, right: this is not PHP, there you have a new db connection on every request. (not really but during a request in PHP the one connection is yours and no other request uses it in the meantime.)

In Node.js however, the connections are managed by the pool. for transactions you take one out, but for data fetching requests, there is no need. just query the db, be happy with data, and the pool manage the connections for you.